# Transistor as a switch with square wave input

Tags: arduino, transistors, circuit-analysis, usb, switches

I want to construct a circuit that contains a transistor and a LED. I have a supply square wave input voltage(0-5v). Help me to construct a circuit when    input is 0v ,if LED on and input is 5v then LED off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transistor-LED Circuit Design Question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595872/transistor-led-circuit-design-question)

Comment: @TimWilliams I think the logic of the question you found is the opposite of what this question is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit may serve your purposes

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKdzFV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the CNTRL input is below 4.3 V, the LED will be on. If the CNTRL input is above 4.3 V, the LED will be off. If you need the threshold voltage to be lower, it can be done, but the circuit will require at least one more component.

This next circuit switches at a lower voltage, but the switching occurs over a much wider range. Since you stated that the input was a square wave, this shouldn't be a significant problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg0Quz.png)</sup>

[image]

If you want the LED to be brighter (either circuit), you can reduce the size of R1, but if you go too low, you may burn out the LED.